# ¿Como llenar un array por medio del bucle for en java?

Tags: java

Hola quiero hacerlo este procedimiento pero no se como.
esto es python:

```
num = 7
for i in range(1,num+1):
numbers = []
numbers.append(i)

for x in numbers:

    print(x,end = " ")
```

aqui el codigo en java pero no me resulta

```
int num = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int array[] = {};
        array.append[i]
```

como ven no puedo llenar ese array como lo hize con python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay cinco cosas, **primero** te falta cerrar una llave (`}`), lo **segundo** es que la razon por la que no te funciona esto:

```
int num = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        int array[] = {};
        array.append[i]
    }
```

Es porque **el array lo estas creando dentro del ciclo y luego se esta destruyendo**, lo que pasa es tu arreglo al ser creado dentro del **for** solo existira dentro del for.

Lo **tercero** es que, ten en cuenta que en `python` las cosas funcionan muy diferentes, en `pyhon` **cuando declaras un `array` no necesitas especificarle la cantidad de espacios que quieres que tenga**.

En `java` esto es diferente, porque para ese tipo de arreglos **siempre debes definir un tamaño**, por lo tanto eso son llamados **arreglos de memoria fija**, y no hay nada que puedas hacer para que puedas usarlos como **arreglos de memoria dinamica**, es decir que **una vez estableces los valores que va a tener o la cantidad de espacios que va a tener el** `array`,  la unica forma de cambiar la cantidad de memoria o espacios que va a usar el array es **redeclarandolo**, lo cual hace que directamente la memoria se vacie.

Para que me entiendas mejor, el **cuarto error** es que tu tienes esto:

```
int array[] = {};
```

Eso es erroneo, hay que corregirlo, ya que los `[]` **no** van después del nombre de la variable, **van despues del tipo** de esta manera:

```
int[] array = {};
```

Ahora que se corrigio ese pequeño detalle, ten en cuenta que cuando usas llaves (`{}`) despues del igual, es porque lo que intentas hacer es asignar valores directamente al array, por lo tanto podrias hacer algo como esto y funcionaria:

```
int[] array = {0, 1, 4, 10};
```

Sin embargo cuando tu dejas vacio las llaves:

```
int[] array = {};
```

Es el equivalente a decir que tu no vas a guardar nada en tu arreglo y **no puedes guardar nada**, es decir, estas definiendo tu array con un espacio en memoria de `0` elementos:

```
int[] array = new int[0];
```

esa seria la otra forma de declarar un array con `x` espacios en memoria, pero sin asignar directamente valores, es decir que seria como tener espacios vacios en memoria asignados que tu luego puedes llenar.

el **quinto problema** es que en esta linea se te olvido un `;` al final, lo he añadido por ti:

```
array.append[i];
```

Dicho esto hagamos la correcion a tu codigo:

```
//El espacio en memoria que tendra el array
int num = 5;
//Creamos un array de 5 espacios basados en num
int array[] = new int[num];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        //accedemos al arreglo en la pocision i (array[i]) y le asignamos i.
        array[i] = i;
    }
```

Si quieres ver el resultado puedes luego imprimir luego `array`:

```
System.out.println(array);
```

Comment: riven iba aceptar tu respuesta pero al imprimir me devuelve esto. [I@7d4991ad

Comment: Eso es porque en java los arreglos no se imprimen directamente, si no que se imprime la direccion de memoria de estos, para poder ver los datos del array en si deberas hacer algo como `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` donde `Arrays` viene `java.util`, de lo contrario lo que estas viendo no es la informacion del array, si no la direccion de memoria del array, algo parecido ocurre en `c++`.

Comment: @Riven La forma como declaró el OP el array es válido. Es decir, este código `int array[];` compila perfectamente en Java. En Java los arrays son objetos y cuando imprimes el "array" directamente su salida no será una dirección de memoria, sino, el valor devuelto por el método toString. Es decir, esto: `System.out.println(array);` es equivalente a esto: `System.out.println(array.toString());`.

Comment: Vale,  intentalo,  a mi me imprime la direccion de memoria al hacerlo como tu dices.

Comment: @Riven ¿Cómo sabes que es la dirección de memoria? No puede ser la dirección base del objeto al que apunte la referencia, porque en Java no es posible imprimir en pantalla la dirección de X variable (ya que es un lenguaje de alto nivel comparado con C/C++). Es más, los primeros caracteres `[I` corresponde al nombre de la clase del objeto al que apunte "array" y lo demás son caracteres "basura". Otra manera para comprobar que no es una dirección de memoria, es ejecutando el programa varias veces, lanzará siempre el mismo resultado.

Comment: Se supone que las direcciones de memoria varían cada vez que se ejecuta el programa y en este caso no pasa.

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo como esto, donde primeramente dimensionas el array `numbers` en base a la variable `num` y agregas los valores al array `numbers`, posteriormente imprimes los valores almacenados en el array:

```
    int num = 7;
    int[] numbers = new int[num];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
        numbers[i] = i+1;              
    }

    
    for (int x : numbers){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

lo que sucede es que python trabaja con listas por eso no es necesario ingresarle el tamaño , en java Debería ser así

```
int num = 7;
      int x = 0;
      List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

      for(int i=1;i < num+1;i++){
          
          numbers.add(i);
          
      }
       for(int i= 0;i<numbers.size();i++){
           System.out.print(numbers.get(i) + " ");
       }
```

o otra solucion podria ser esta, si en vez de listas quieres hacerlo con arreglos :

```
 int num = 7;
  int x = 0;
  int numbers[] = new int[num];
  for(int i=1;i < num+1;i++){
      
      numbers[x]= i;
      x++;
  }
   for(int i:numbers){
       System.out.print(i + " ");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar dos ciclos for como es lo más habitual en java:

```
int num = 7;
int array[] = new int[num]; // se inicializa el array con un tamaño.
// se llena el array con un ciclo for.
for (int i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
  array[i] = i;
}

// se imprime el array con un for
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
}
```

Si lo quieres hacer de otra forma haciendo uso de Java 8, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
// genera un rango de números
    IntStream stream = IntStream.range(1, num); 
// el método range devuelve un objeto de tipo IntStream, por lo que se debe convertir a Array.
    int[] arr = stream.toArray();
// Se imprime sin hacer uso de for mediante la claseArray y su método toString()
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Aquí te dejo el [ejemplo](https://repl.it/repls/HastySlipperyBlogs#Main.java) para que lo puedas correr en línea.